# grep specific parameter from a file

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, grep

I'm trying to get the directory path from the grep result, so that i can remove the directory when the backup fails.

So how do i get the target-dir (exactly /backups/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-08_09-35-42) from below.

```
val=`grep -F -m 1 'target-dir=' innobackupex-runner.11498.tmp`
 echo $val
150408 09:35:42 innobackupex: Starting ibbackup with command: xtrabackup --defaults-group="mysqld" --backup --suspend-at-end --target-dir=/backups/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-08_09-35-42 --innodb_data_file_path="ibdata1:12M:autoextend" --tmpdir=/tmp --tables='.*[.].*' --extra-lsndir='/tmp' --incremental-basedir='/backups/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-08_09-28-04'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of grep supports Perl (`-P`) mode, you could do this:

```
val=$(grep -oP -m1 'target-dir=\K\S+' innobackupex-runner.11498.tmp)
```

The `-o` switch means that only the matching part is printed. The `\K` "kills" the part before, leaving you with only the non-space characters after the `=` sign.

You will run into problems if your file name contains spaces!

Another option, using sed:

```
val=$(sed -n 's/.*target-dir=\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p;q' innobackupex-runner.11498.tmp)
```

This does effectively the same thing but uses basic regular expressions, which are supported in any POSIX-compliant version of sed.

Slightly shorter, using extended regular expressions (`-r` or `-E` with BSD sed):

```
val=$(sed -rn 's/.*target-dir=([^[:space:]]+).*/\1/p;q' innobackupex-runner.11498.tmp)
```

Comment: This works good. From which version -P is started supporting? I just want to make sure it works for older version such as centos5

Comment: As long as you're using GNU grep, I think that the Perl option has been around for a while.

Comment: @user1595858 I've also added a version using sed in case you're concerned about compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
val=`grep -F -m 1 'target-dir=' innobackupex-runner.11498.tmp | sed 's/..*target_dir=\(..*\) --innodb..*/\1/' `
```

Comment: no luck with it.  grep -F -m 1 'target-dir=' innobackupex-runner.11498.tmp | sed 's/..*target_dir=\(..*\) --innodb..*/\1/' 
150408 09:35:42  innobackupex: Starting ibbackup with command: xtrabackup  --defaults-group="mysqld" --backup --suspend-at-end --target-dir=/backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-08_09-35-42 --innodb_data_file_path="ibdata1:12M:autoextend" --tmpdir=/tmp --tables='.*[.].*' --extra-lsndir='/tmp' --incremental-basedir='/backups/xtrabackup/incr/2015-04-07_10-00-01/2015-04-08_09-28-04'

Comment: change the sed command to " sed '1,$s/^..*--target-dir=//' | sed 's/ ..*$//'"

Comment: Explanation please !!